# Maximizing a sum

Tags: optimization, summation

$f(x) = maximize_{t \in \{1,-1\}} (\sum_{j=1}^d t x_j)$

$g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^d maximize_{t \in \{1,-1\}} (t x_j)$

How can I prove whether $f(x) = g(x)$ or not?

Comment: Think about what it means to maximize $t\cdot a$, where $a$ is given, and $t$ lies in a range. Which values of $t$ might we take and when might we take which value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of $f$, you can pull the $t$ out as a common factor of the sum so $f(x) = \max_{t\in\{-1, 1\}}\left(t\sum x_j\right)$, which pretty easily resolves to $f(x) = \left|\sum x_j\right|$.

Whereas, using a similar argument, $g(x) = \sum |x_j|$.

So by the triangle inequality, $f(x) \le g(x)$ with equality only happening if all of the $x_j$ have the same sign, i.e. either $\forall j\ x_j \ge 0$ or $\forall j\ x_j \le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1=1$, $x_2=-1$.

$$f(1,-1)=\max_{t \in \left\{1, -1\right\}} t-t=0$$

$$g(1,-1)=\max_{t \in \left\{1, -1\right\}} t + \max_{t \in \left\{1, -1\right\}}(-t)=2$$